# Should CSRF tokens protect against crafting a CSRF request by someone who has access to the same computer?

Tags: csrf

My server generates a random CRSF token if it doesn't find one in the cookies and saves it to the cookies encrypted, and supplies the raw token in the body of the response, to be read by an SPA and sent back as a header in form POST submissions...

Should I force the regeneration of the token on login/logout?

I suspect that it would be a security vulnerability if I don't, because then, I can open the website, get the crsf token, hand the device to an unsuspecting guest, they log in, they still have the same csrf token I know, so I can send them a link and make them perform any action since I know the correct csrf.

The downside is that once you log in or log out, any tabs open (even if the form doesn't need an account) will get out of sync with the csrf token.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The tokens should be generated once per session or per request.  The purpose of these tokens is to tie the session to the form.  So if you follow that guidance you will have a new one after a login happens and a new session has begun.  (If you start the session before login, you've opened a security hole... "session fixation".... which might be what you are getting at here... securing the session or authenticating the user are separate concerns.)

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for the clarification. I don't really have a "session". I'm saving the cookies manually. So I have my auth_token and csrf_token. But I assume what you mean is that I should clear all cookies and regenerate them once a "logical session" ends, so on login/logout.

Comment: The auth_token preserves your session.  (If you don't have a session, the user would have to re-enter credentials for every action requiring authorization)  You can just update the cookie on login.  (and probably on refreshing the token if you do that)  Updating the csrf token for each form is a good idea, too.  It depends on how secure you want to be.  (Handing someone your computer doesn't seem all that secure, though...)  Remember that the cookie will be sent automatically to same-domain, the malicious actor's hang-up is providing the correct hidden field to match.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are.

If you are the owner of the device, you can do something worse than stealing CSRF tokens. A keylogger or a malicious mirror will be way more damaging than stealing a token.

You could re-create CSRF tokens at login (it's not resource intensive anyway) for starting things fresh on every login, but not because you would be plugging a hole.

Comment: Right, but imagine you gave your device to a friend for a minute to check their account after you logged out, and you were using a non-admin user, so they can't install malicious things, but can steal your CSRF token. Yes, I understand this is a very minor threat vector, hence my question about whether regenerating csrf tokens on login/logout is even worth it?

Answer (score 0):

Not regenerating the CSRF would allow for a session fixation attack on the CSRF (a 'CSRF fixation attack').

There's no need to share devices.

Suppose that Bob has an account at example.com

Eve wants to fiddle with it, but although Bob connects through a network controlled by Eve, there is a CSRF blocking her.

- Eve obtains a CSRF cookie ("ABCD") and its CSRF token ("1234")
- At one point, Bob visits example web page by writing in his browser bar "example.com"
- Bob's browser process that request loading **http://** example.com
- Usually http://example.com would simply redirect to https://example.com but Eve intercepts that and additionally adds a `Cookie: csrf=ABCD`
- Given that there is a CSRF cookie, the server uses `1234` as CSRF, even after he logs in

On a normal session fixation attack, the cookie would be the session one, and Eve would be able to browse the site as Bob. Here we are assuming this only affects the CSRF, so this 'only' allows her to bypass the CSRF protection, by knowing the token will be `1234`. Thus, she can produce a POST to https://example.com/ with the right CSRF, having that take action under Bob account.

Regarding

> any tabs open (even if the form doesn't need an account) will get out of sync with the csrf token.

If the open tab was filled under a different status, you may not want to change that unexpectedly. If it was filled anonymously, it may be undesirable to post it under the  RationalFragile name. Or if it was written as  RationalFragile, you may not want to post it anonymously because the user signed out in a different tab.

By all means, don't make the user lose its form content, but actually making the "Save" a "Preview", forcing the user to confirm it again may actually be the proper behavior.

Comment: Good point on non encrypted http, but aren't you forgetting that I encrypt cookies (and set them as https only). So even if somehow the user sent the cookies in an http request (which the backend will redirect to https), no one can read the cookies anyway, and the backend sends the raw csrf only over https. The concern would be if the user submits a form with the correct csrf over http, but they can't since the backend serves forms over https, and cross domain POST won't have the csrf.

Comment: @RationalFragile this is a sessión fixation. Eve can fetch a https page from your site and get a valid encrypted cookie and the corresponding CSRF value, so the cookie encryption (that not everyone will be doing) doesn't protect you.

Comment: My server does not provide the csrf token over http, it only provides it over https, so it cannot be eavesdropped on the network, right? But the point from encrypting the cookie is that if I don't, the raw token will be transmitted over http before my server can redirect to https. (But, as I said, this is sort of redundant since there is an option to set cookie as https only, but I encrypt all cookies used only by the server anyway). Does that make sense?

Comment: No, the evil server can fetch from https, then present it through http

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. If the evil server can pretend to be my server then all is lost, it can be a proxy relaying things to me and I would have no way of knowing. By contrast, if the evil server presents it to my server on http, it'll get redirected since my server doesn't accept http. I'm sorry but please explain more or link something I can read to understand.

Comment: @RationalFragile evil server downloads your page through https, then serves it with http to unsuspecting visitor.